# How many ways we can send data from one app to another app securely in Android

Tags: android

I tried to search many forums, blogs, and stack overflow link but I am unable to find how many ways we can transfer data from one app to SecondAPP in another securely.

I am trying to set some value in OneAPP like

```
String myString = "Hellow World!"
```

I am trying to get value in another app SecondAPP

```
String myString = getValue;
```

Please help and suggest how many ways we can achieve and which one is more secure.

Thanks

Comment: Check ContentProviders or Bound Services

Comment: can you help me please with any link from where i can refer